# Is there a way to change the site title depending on the language?

Tags: multi-language

I have a multi-lang website, that is based on bossa themes. I use [PolyLang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) Plugin for the multi-lang. I want to change the website title depending on the language. Is there a way to achieve this? I can edit the PHP files if this is the answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm surprised PolyLang doesn't support this already. Off the top of my head I can't see a single filter for this so you probably want to hook [pre_option_blogname](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_option/) or [option_blogname](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_option/) and switch the value based on language from PolyLang, assuming this is called after PolyLang is sufficiently initialised. Ditto the site subtitle. I haven't done enough investigation to write an answer though.

Comment: Yes PolyLang already supports this - see [PLL_Base::init()](https://github.com/polylang/polylang/blob/057771440c23033b609374b7d2b62923fcaddc49/include/base.php#L84) which registers blogname and blogdescription as translatable options. Please ask PolyLang for help directly if this isn't working for you.

Comment: Thank you rup. Is there documentation for it since I am a total newbie. For now I just use the tag line and both names appear